# Mongoose model not including added value when returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do two queryies and then combine them and send it back to the client... here is my middleware:

```
exports.shipmentByID = function(req, res, next, id) { 
    Shipment.findById(id)
        .populate('user', 'displayName')
        .exec(function(err, shipment) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (! shipment) return next(new Error('Failed to load Shipment ' + id));

            VendorInvoice.find({ shipment: id })
                .exec(function (err, vendorInvoices) {
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    if (! vendorInvoices) return next(new Error('Failed to load Shipment ' + id));

                    shipment.vendorInvoices = vendorInvoices;

                    req.shipment = shipment;
                    next();
                });
        });
};
```

And the controller method that is called

```
exports.read = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.shipment.vendorInvoices); // note this prints the data I am looking for
    res.jsonp(req.shipment);
};
```

But then on the client all I get back is all of the values but vendorInvoices:

```
{
  __v: 0
  _id: "5583af682b46ec9353963dc4"
  created: "2015-06-19T05:58:00.434Z"
  dateInvoiced: "2015-06-18T07:00:00.000Z"
  shipmentId: "12345"
  user: {_id: "549268852f54d06f4d0720ce", displayName: "troy Cosentino"}
}
```

I'm stuck, why wouldn't that pass through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities

1. Return a plain object.

   var s = shipment.toJSON();
   s.vendorInvoice = vendorInvoice;
2. Implement the toJSON method that checks for the added value.
   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON

Comment: The Mongoose `.toJSON()` is a method that is used to sanitize/customize objects before `JSON.stringify()` (which always checks objects for `.toJSON` methods before stringifying). Arguably it is not actually meant to be called directly. Using the Mongoose `.toObject()` is better as it's specifically meant to create "inert" objects in this fashion. If you want to "activate" `.toJSON`, use `JSON.stringify` on the model instance.

Comment: Thanks, plain object makes sense. I assume that the reason I was not seeing the data was because the native toJSON wasn't picking it up.. must be some sort of key registration under the hood that the method checks for. Thanks!

Comment: @TroyCosentino can you mark the answer as correct if that solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could try returning a plain JavaScript object instead of the Mongoose model instance by calling the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method on the query chain as follows:

```
Shipment.findById(id)
    .populate('user', 'displayName')
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, shipment){
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (! shipment) return next(new Error('Failed to load Shipment ' + id));

        VendorInvoice.find({ shipment: id })
            .exec(function (err, vendorInvoices) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                if (! vendorInvoices) return next(new Error('Failed to load Shipment ' + id));

                shipment.vendorInvoices = vendorInvoices;

                req.shipment = shipment;
                next();
            });

});
```